# Manipulate (str.replace) array data that comes back over autocomplete

Tags: javascript, replace

```
$('#groupnamesearch').blur(function () {
    str = $('#groupnamesearch').val()
    $.get("injectgroup.php", {
        name: str
    }, function (data) {
        //here i guess str.replace data
        $('#aspecforgroup').val(data);
    });
});
```

This gives me results like: ["45054","55905","42306"]

I'd like to strip all []" of them, so I have only numbers and the , character.

How can I manipulate the data that came over the ajax request before it's getting populated in an input field?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your result a string? "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]" or is it an actual array? If your numbers are real numbers, you shouldn't have to quote them when you send them in the result. (ie: none have lots of zeros at the beginning like 00001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result that you are getting back in `data` is an actual string - and I assume it must be if the square brackets are getting displayed in your "aspecforgroup" field - then you can remove those characters as follows:

```
data = data.replace(/[\[\]"]/g, "");
```

Or you can tell jQuery (that *is* jQuery that you're using?) to treat the response as JSON in which case it should be automatically parsed into an array by the time it ends up in the `data` parameter and then you can use the array [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn that into a string:

```
$.get("injectgroup.php", {
    name: str
}, function (data) {
    $('#aspecforgroup').val(data.join(","));
}, "json");
```

The parameter to `.join()` is the string to join the individual elements with. If you leave it out it will be a comma by default, but you might want to use a comma plus a space: `.join(", ")`.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I forgot to explain the regular expression in the `.replace()` part of my answer. If you're not familiar with regex I suggest starting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), or there are any number of regex tutorials that you can find with Google. Note that if your JS is going to treat the Ajax response as a plain string then you might as well update your PHP to return it in the format you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with array [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

if your data is string, you have to first parse the string to convert an array and then do a join like this -

```
var newData = JSON.parse(data).join();
```

Comment: Because it's serialized, I'm supposed to either set  format json before the get request I have, which I don't know how to do, OR set content type header in PHP, but that I had never done before, then It'd automatically leave the characters I want to replace. I guess that'd be  more professional, no? But how? :D

Comment: And still, because I'm a complete noob over JS, this still doesn't help, because var data = data.join(); is not okay :)

Comment: @Flatline - use some other variable name to hold your join, var newData = data.join(); if your data is a string array like you mentioned in the question, this should definitely work.

Comment: john thanks, but chrome console error:


Uncaught TypeError: Object ["45054","55905","42306"]
 has no method 'join' cont-character.php:133

Comment: @Flatline - edited my answer- I am guessing your returned data is a string - not an array.

Answer (score 0):

if `data` is a string:

```
data = '["45054","55905","42306"]';
var output​ = JSON.parse(data).join(', ');
​alert(output)​;
```

if `data` is already an array:

```
data = ["45054","55905","42306"];
var output = data.join(', ');
alert(output);
```

both output this:

```
45054, 55905, 42306
```